# RxJava - Iterating a Single<Collection>

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I have a method which returns a Single<Collection<SomeObj>>. What is the correct way to iterate through it so I can apply a filter and only return the SomeObj I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [flattenAsObservable](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#flattenAsObservable-io.reactivex.functions.Function-). It converts a single of an iterable to an observable that emits each item:

```
getItems()
    .flattenAsObservable { it }
    .filter { <some condition> }
    .first()
```

Here the `getItems` returns `Single<Collection<SomeObj>>`.

This code will return an observable. You might need to convert it back to a single. Be careful, if there are no elements, then it cannot be covered to single unless you specify a default value.